# EF Code First entity columns in subclass

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am experimenting with EF Code First and have created the entity `Article`:

```
public class Article
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTimeRange Published { get; set; }
}
```

Since there will be many entities needing a range, I thought it would be easier to create a class `DateTimeRange`:

```
public class DateTimeRange
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

The code generation works quite well, and this is the result:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Articles",
    c => new
        {
            ArticleId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            Published_From = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            Published_To = c.DateTime(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ArticleId);
```

However, I'd like the column names to be generated without an underscore. I tried giving the columns `From` and `To` specific names:

```
[Required, Column("PublishedFrom")]
public DateTime From { get; set; }

[Column("PublishedTo")]
public DateTime? To { get; set; }
```

which works perfectly:

```
PublishedFrom = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
PublishedTo = c.DateTime()
```

Thing is: like I said, I'd like to use this in several entities and maybe even multiple times in the same entity, so giving a fixed name in the `DateTimeRange` will not work. I'd prefer to just be able to say to concatenate the names without an underscore.
Is there any way to do that?

**UPDATE**
That's my current solution which I got with the help from the link provided by virusstorm

```
[ComplexType]
public class DateTimeRange
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

and then, in the DBContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<Article>().Configure(config => config.Property(article => article.Published.From).HasColumnName("PublishedFrom"));
    modelBuilder.Types<Article>().Configure(config => config.Property(article => article.Published.To).HasColumnName("PublishedTo"));
}
```

Comment: Look at Code-first custom conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `DateTimeRange` a complex type in Entity Framework with an attribute. You will then need to add setup details in the `OnModelCreating` method. Take a look at [Making Complex Types Useful with Entity Framework 6 Custom Configurations](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx). This should set you down the right path.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. However, with this solution, I'll have to set up a convention for both fields every time they are used. Is there any way to make this generic? I tried using modelBuilder.Types().Configure() instead of modelBuilder.Types<Article>().Configure() but can't get it to work.

Comment: There are ways to achieve this via interfaces and reflection. I typically don't recommend it though as reflection does have a performance cost to it. Because of the way Entity Framework is designed, there isn't a good way to make this truly generic or abstract. You can always make a case for it and recommend it as a feature.

https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-core-feature-suggestions

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code in the link. If the link breaks this answer is useless.

Comment: I have updated my question with the current solution, based on the content of the link in the comment by @virusstorm